# How to do this under linux/unix?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

There have a million webpages, each page may have some phone numbers with two
formats (XXX)XXX-XXXX, XXX-XXX-XXXX, how to find them out and update them into a unified format, i.e., 1-xxx-xxx-xxxx. How to do that using Linux or Unix commands?

Comment: I get the feeling `sed` and `awk` will be of great use to you. Now if only I knew enough about them to 'give you teh codez'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 cat ph.txt  
111-222-3333-4444
(222)-234-2932-2929
212-939-2929-2929
```

using sed you can change millon webpages

```
 cat ph.txt  | sed -e 's/^(//;s/)//;s/^/1-/'
1-111-222-3333-4444
1-222-234-2932-2929
1-212-939-2929-2929
```

for all html files

```
find dirname -type f -name "*.html" -exec sed -e 's/^(//;s/)//;s/^/1-/' {} \;
```

Comment: What if there are other parentheses in the file that you want to keep?

Comment: yeah,actually i have given basic answer.depend on the symbol in the file ,we can improve the sed

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/(\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\))\([[:digit:]]\{3\}-[[:digit:]]\{4\}\)/\1-\2/g'  -e 's/[[:digit:]]\{3\}-[[:digit:]]\{3\}-[[:digit:]]\{4\}/1-&/g'
```

Something like that. First command changes parenthesis' style to hyphen style, second command adds **1-** to it.

Answer (score 0):

This command works with either format in one step:

```
sed 's/(\?\([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)[)-]\?\([[:digit:]]\{3\}-[[:digit:]]\{4\}\)/1-\1-\2/g' inputfile
```

It will change other number formats, too, though, including "123456-7890", "(123456-7890" and "123)456-7890".